# Can Groovy dynamically add or override a method on a POJO?

Tags: java, groovy

If I have

```
// java
class MyClass {
   public String getName() {
     return "hector";
   }
}
```

and an instance of this class.  Can Groovy override the getName() method on the instance?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Of course you can using [Dynamic MetaClass](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_per_instance_metaclass).

Your case is specifically covered by the following example :

```
def object = new MyClass();
object.metaClass.getName = { "Jake" }
assert "Jake" == object.getName()
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that dynamically-added methods will only be seen / can only be invoked by Groovy code.